# Practical approaches to working with nonplanar commutative diagrams?

Tags: category-theory, diagram-chasing

The 4-associahedron is the 4-dimensional version of Mac Lane's pentagon diagram.  If you look at [Trimble's notes on tetracategories](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/tetracategories.html), you can see the obvious difficulty in working with such a diagram (using it to verify things like coherence etc).  Are there any techniques and/or approaches to working with  such unwieldy higher-dimensional diagrams?

Comment: Borrow a 3d printer? :-)